The phantom mobile app accesses the website and cannot use the phone camera
What is the reason why no data is returned when using the mobile phone camera when accessing the website we developed using the built-in browser of the phantom mobile application?
For example, this website cannot display the camera content properly: https://mediapipe-studio.webapps.google.com/demo/face_detector?hl=zh-cn
